# Combined order with association in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, pagination

I have two models, post and comment. Posts has many comments and comments belongs to posts.

What I'm trying to do, is to have a list of posts that is ordered by creation date, unless it has comments. Then it needs to take the creation date of the latest comment.

Now I know that I can include associations like this:

```rb
Post.find(:all, :include => [:comments], :order => "comments.created_at DESC, posts.created_at DESC")
```

But this will order all posts with comments first and then the posts without comments. I don't want either ones ordered separately, but combined.

The solution also needs to be compatible with a paginate gem like will_paginate.

**Edit**

I have it now working with the following code:

```rb
posts_controller.rb

@posts = Post.order('updated_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per_page(10)
```

```rb
comments_controller.rb

@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
@post.update_attributes!(:updated_at => Time.now)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend:
Add a last_commented_at date field to your Post model. Whenever someone comments on the post update that field. It de-normalizes your db structure a bit, but your query will be faster and more strait-forward.

Answer (score 1):

**Postgres**

```
Post.paginate(:include => [:comments],
  :order => "COALESCE(comments.created_at, posts.created_at)",
  :page => 1, :per_page => 10)
```

**MySQL**

```
Post.paginate(:include => [:comments], 
  :order => "IFNULL(comments.created_at, posts.created_at)", 
  :page => 1, :per_page => 10)
```

Comment: Updated the answer with a better solution, take a look.

Comment: Well what does it mean to sort posts desc and comments asc. You are dealing with one set so the entire set has to have one sort order.  May be you can give more details of your requirement.

Comment: the latest post (whether it has a comment or not) goes to the top. but under every post, the comments are displayed in the order they where posted. so the first on top.